# Split a list into a dictionary

Tags: python

I am trying to split my list into a dictionary and I wrote a function for it. It takes in a list and gets the list length. If the length of the list is 253 , it creates a dictionary with 26 keys - this is calculated by rounding up the number to a higher 10 (250 will create 25 keys, 251-259 will create 26 keys). Each key will store a chuck of the original list (as of now I am storing 10 elements per list).

I want to know if I can improve it more:

```
def limit_files(file_list, at_a_time=10):

    l = file_list
    n = len(l)
    d, r = divmod(n, at_a_time) 

    num_keys = d + 1 if r else d   
    slice = n // num_keys
    vals = (l[i:i+slice] for i in range(0, n, slice+1)) 
    dct = dict(zip(range(1,num_keys+1),vals))
    return (dct)
```

Comment: I'm curious — why would you want to construct such a dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution doesn't really work as intended:

```
In [1]: q = [10,20,30,50,30,2,2,4,3,4,2,3,5,2,3,2]
In [2]: limit_files(q)
Out[2]: {1: [10, 20, 30, 50, 30, 2, 2, 4], 2: [4, 2, 3, 5, 2, 3, 2]}
In [3]: len(limit_files(q, at_a_time=10)[1])
Out[3]: 8
```

And it's a pain to debug because there are lots of different variables to keep in your head!

---

Now, let's do some improvements.

**Renaming**

The current function name doesn't really tell me what it does... Let's change it for a more appropriate one.

Does the function really only works on "files"? It would work on every list! What does it do? Well, it takes a list, slice it into smaller chunk and groups them into a dictionary. Perhaps it's not the best name but `slice_and_group` seems fine. It tells at least a bit about the function.

**Export the splitting to an external function**

The slicing algorithm can definitively see use elsewhere, so we take that out.

```
def slice_list(lst, slice_size):
    if not isinstance(slice_size, int) or slice_size <= 0:
        raise ValueError("slice_size must be a positive integer")

    for i in xrange(0, len(lst), slice_size):
        yield lst[i:i+slice_size]
```

**Putting things together**

Now it's really easy to reason about what you want:

- Create the dictionary of the slices
- Slice the entered list
- Match an int with each of the slices
- Put that in the dict
- Return the dict

My implementation:

```
def slice_and_group(lst, slice_size=10):
    slices = {}
    for i,l in enumerate(slice_list(lst, slice_size)):
        slices[i] = l

    return slices
```

I find this solution more pythonic because there is no "magic variable" in the code, it uses `enumerate` to match the int to the slice, and a simple loop to assign the value. Easy and readable!

Answer (score 1):

- First of all there is a bug in your code, `range(0, n, slice+1)` should be `range(0, n, slice)` otherwise you'll miss every (slice+1)<sup>th</sup> item.
- I don't understand why you re-assigned `l = file_list` to `l` here, note that simple assignments in Python don't create a copy of the object. Also don't use `l` as a variable name because it looks like `1`(one) in many fonts.
- If you're using Python 2 then use `xrange()` instead of `range()`.
- `dict(zip(range(1,num_keys+1),vals))` can be replace with a simpler `dict(enumerate(vals, start=1))`
- The parenthesis around `(dict)` in return statement are unnecessary.
- `slice` is a built-in function, so try not to use it as a variable name. `slice_size` is one alternative.

Also I don't understand why you need a dict here, you can simply use a list of lists. Then the only difference will be that you'll have to start indexing at 0. Indexing is very faster than dictionary key-lookups and will also make sure the order of items is maintained.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The `enumerate` was a much better way to create the dict. i dont have enough 'rep' to upvote your answer but ill make sure i come back some day and do it